# Django : Auto Generate Adobe Illustrator Image Previews

Tags: django, adobe, django-views, adobe-illustrator

If a user uploads a .AI file, how can I auto-generate a image preview of the file inside? Mac OS X 10.8 does it with a "spacebar" preview but I'd love to be able to do it in my web-based django project.

I don't need to create an AI file, I just need to create a preview of a previously made file.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The reason Mac OS 10.8 can generate a preview is because Illustrator saves a PDF with the file by default. [This website](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/02/24/opening-adobe-illustrator-ai-files-when-you-don-t-have-adobe-illustrator.aspx) may help.

Comment: how then, do you make a preview of the psd in python?